# Load specific part of CZML file according to ID

Tags: cesiumjs, czml

In the Cesium demo [here](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=CZML.html), you have the option to select choose what data you want to view by simple changing where you are reading the data from.

I want the "Satellites" button to only display those with "Satellite" in the id from the CZML file and ignore the rest, currently my code looks like this:

```js
Sandcastle.addDefaultToolbarButton("Satellites", function () {  
    Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load("../SampleData/simple.czml").then(function(dataSource) {
    viewer.clock.multiplier = 1;
    var entity = dataSource.entities.getById("Satellite");

    viewer.dataSources.add(entity);
  });
  viewer.camera.flyHome(0);
});
```

However when I try this nothing is shown. I also tried just with the Vehicle (only has 1 entity in it and ID is exactly "Vehicle") so I could check if it is getting the data properly however I got this error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')" when clicking on the vehicle button

Here is my for the Vehicle section:

```js
Sandcastle.addToolbarButton("Vehicle", function () {
  Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load("../SampleData/Vehicle.czml").then(function(dataSource) {
    viewer.clock.multiplier = 1;

    var entity = dataSource.entities.getById("Vehicle");
    viewer.dataSources.add(entity);
  });
  
  viewer.scene.camera.setView({
    destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-116.52, 35.02, 95000),
    orientation: {
      heading: 6,
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [corrected Sandcastle demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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).

Some issues in the original:

- You have a bad ID in one `"Satellite"` instead of `"Satellite/Geoeye1"`, so the entity was not found.
- You shouldn't pass an individual entity to `viewer.dataSources.add()`, instead use `viewer.entities.add()` for this.
- The most important, often overlooked problem, is the clock was set wrong.  These entities exist for a range of time (several years ago when the sample scenario was first created), and they don't exist in the present.  Normally when adding a dataSource to the viewer, the clock automatically updates, but in this case adding a single entity does not do that, so the clock shows the current time instead of a time when the entity exists.  There are several ways to fix this, but I chose this one:

```js
    viewer.clock.currentTime = dataSource.clock.startTime;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response that is very helpful.

Is there any way to rather than select by a specific ID, select them so that all entities with "Satellite" in the ID are loaded?

Comment: In the load callback, you can filter the list with `dataSource.entities.values.filter(e => e.id.startsWith("Satellite"))`.  Iterate through that array, and add each entity to the viewer.